# Redirección de una alerta Stock

Tags: php, html

Estaba tratando de implantar una alerta a mi código de forma que, cuando el producto sobrepasara el número establecido de inventario; enviara un email de error al admin.

Al principio me funcionó perfectamente, pero al realizar un pedido con 1 producto que consta con 5 en el inventario, no se efectúa el pedido sino que me envía la alerta de Stock; teniendo 5 productos en inventario.

Es este el código que estoy usando para la alerta, ¿hay algo mal en él? ¡Gracias!

```
<?php
```

session_start();

include'../php/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['datos_login'])){

```
header("location: ../compra/login.php");
```

}

$arregloCliente = $_SESSION['datos_log'];

$arregloUsuario = $_SESSION['datos_login'];

$arregloInv = $_SESSION['datos_login'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['compra'])){header("location: ../login.php");}

$arreglo = $_SESSION['compra'];

$total=0;

for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){

```
$total= $total+($arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']);
```

}
//email alarma stock

$conexion->query("select * from productos where id=Id ")or die($conexion->error);

```
                 for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
                   
                    if($arreglo[$i]['Inventario'] < $arreglo[$i]['Cantidad']){
                        include"../php/enviarMail-stock.php";
                        
                        header("location: admin.php?error=No se puede realizar el pedido.<br> La cantidad solicitada excede el inventario.<br>Por favor intente de nuevo o comuniquese con el administrador.");
                        
                        unset($_SESSION['compra']);
```

Comment: Veo el código un poco extraño. Creo que te falta crear y llenar el array $arreglo, lo puedes hacer con **fetch_all**:   
No se como es el resto del código pero tener un include dentro de un bucle no es buena práctica. Haz una llamada a la función que uses pera enviar el correo

//email alarma stock
$resultado = $conexion->query("select * from productos where id=Id ")or die($conexion->error);
$arreglo = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //falta esto en tu código

Comment: ¡Saludos! No me funcionó, o quizá no supe cómo ubicarlo en mi código. Quizá deba mostrar más de mi código, desde mi línea 1 hasta la alarma Stock.

Comment: Muestra los cambios que has hecho.

Comment: Recién acabo de editar la publicación de arriba.

Comment: Pero lo que hice fue agregar la sesión hasta el stock. Y, cuando coloqué la sugerencia suya; la coloqué encima de el for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++;

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que no te avisé del query, pones where id=id, te va a devolver toda la tabla.  Probablemente se te fué el dedo y quisiste poner id=$id, donde $id será supongo la variable que contiene el valor que quieres consultar.